# How to extract a string with RegExp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, extract, match

I want extract an Id from the string `<p>id = 22<p>\n<p>1. iteration, 1. task<p>`

with:

```
var str="<p>id = 22<p>\n<p>1. iteration, 1. task<p>";
var patt1=/<p>id = (.*)<p>/;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

but somehow it returns to the browser:

```
id = 22 
,22
```

Why so? Why 2 matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` is a grouping operator useful for extracting portions of the match. If you just want to extract the id then use `str.match(patt1)[1]`

Comment: This will cause a exception if no match is found

Answer (score 0):

```
/<p>id[^<]+<p>/
```

Seems to be a better fit for your task. But your input string is very confusing. Shouldn't it be some HTML open-closed tags sequence?